# variable is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET.

My questions is I have a textbox and input data to database

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_hello" runat="server"  Width="130px"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

and then I can connect to database but when I input the 'hello' in column and submit, it will pop up the errror message:

> 'txt_hello' is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```vb
Dim hello as String = txt.hello

If xxx  Then
sqlUpdate = "UPDATE xxx SET server='" ,Hello=" & hello & " 
ElseIf xxx Then
sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO xxx (Hello ) values ("& hello & ")"
```

My database table column name is "Hello".

Can anyone can give me advice?

Comment: It looks like something went missing when you posted the code: `txt_hello` does not appear in it. Mary gave a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67719004/1115360), but also you need to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project *and* make it the default for new VB projects - that would have let Visual Studio tell you that there was a problem even before you tried running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never concatenate strings to build sql strings. Always use parematers. The `Using...End Using` block assures that the connection is closed and disposed and the command is disposed.

```
    Dim sql As String
    If Condition1 Then
        sql = "UPDATE SomeTableName SET Hello= @Hello;"
    ElseIf Condition2 Then
        sql = "INSERT INTO SomeTableName (Hello ) values (@Hello);"
    Else
        Return
    End If
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hello", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_Hello.Text
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

```
txt_hello.Text
```

`txt_hello` is a control (TextBox), not a string. Its `Text` property  is string.

Comment: Hello @Yuti Orlinsky, thank your reply, i try to instead txt_hello to txt_hello.text but not work.:(

Comment: Had you replaced `Dim hello as String = txt.hello` with `Dim hello as String = txt_hello.Text`?